# Wrapping parent around position relative child

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to get the outer div to wrap the 2 inner divs tightly? i.e. to be of height 150px.

```
<div>
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:#00cc00;"></div>
    <div style="height:100px; background-color:#cc0000; position:relative; top:-50px;"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/44wsagv7/6/

In my actual application the inner divs are variable height, so fixing the height of the outer div is not an option

Comment: elaborate a bit.

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the outer div to 150px?

Comment: Ah, should have said, In my actual application the inner divs are variable height, so fixing the height of the outer div is not an option.

Comment: use min-height:150px and if the height increase it will auto adjsut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some negative bottom margin to the second inner div.

```
position:relative;
top: -50px;
margin-bottom: -50px;
```

And add this to outer div to avoid margin collapsing.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #000000; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="height:100px; background-color: #00cc00;">
  </div>
  <div style="height:100px; background-color: #cc0000; position:relative; top: -50px; margin-bottom: -50px">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can probably use only negative top margin to achieve same layout.

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #000000;">
  <div style="height:100px; background-color: #00cc00;">
  </div>
  <div style="height:100px; background-color: #cc0000; margin-top: -50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the outer `div` to be a specific size (150px for example) just give the outer `div` a fixed height.

```
<div style="height:150px">
  <div style="height:100px; background-color: #00cc00;">
  </div>
  <div style="height:100px; background-color: #cc0000; position:relative; top: -50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add height to the parent div, It will sol. your problem of extra space at bottom.

```
<div style='height:150px;'>
<div style="height:100px; background-color: #00cc00;">
</div>
<div style="height:100px; background-color: #cc0000; position:relative; top: -50px;">
</div>
</div>
```